# Prevent mouse position drifting when dragging a scaled image

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas

I have a system to scale, rotate, and translate an image on a canvas. Everything is working as expected, except the translation of the image after scaling.

When the scale is not equal to `1`, then the dragging starts to drift (see example illustration below):

[image]

The illustration above shows where I start dragging the image, and where my mouse position ends up.

Is there a way of maintaining the mouse position, so that when I'm dragging the image, the mouse stays in the same location of the image?

How can I achieve this, whilst still keeping the rest of the scaling and rotation (from the canvas centre) functionality?

[**Full CodeSandbox demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-bush-j1dgi2?file=/src/index.js)

```js
let rotation = 0;
let scale = 1;
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let startX = 0;
let startY = 0;
let lastX = 0;
let lastY = 0;
let pointerDown = false;

const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const imgWidth = 480;
const imgHeight = 300;

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

resizeCanvas();
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);

const img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/3q3kNGh.png";

function onPointerDown(event) {
  pointerDown = true;
  startX = (event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft) / imgWidth;
  startY = (event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop) / imgHeight;
}

function onPointerMove(event) {
  if (!pointerDown) return;
  let deltaX = (event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft) / imgWidth - startX;
  let deltaY = (event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop) / imgHeight - startY;
  const { x: dX, y: dY } = rotate(
    deltaX * imgWidth,
    deltaY * imgHeight,
    rotation
  );
  x = lastX + dX / imgWidth;
  y = lastY + dY / imgHeight;
}

function onPointerUp() {
  pointerDown = false;
  lastX = x;
  lastY = y;
}

window.addEventListener("pointerdown", onPointerDown);
window.addEventListener("pointermove", onPointerMove);
window.addEventListener("pointerup", onPointerUp);

window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  const key = event.key.toLowerCase();
  switch (key) {
    case "r":
      rotation = (rotation + 5) % 360;
      break;
    case "-":
      scale = Math.max(0, scale - 0.1);
      break;
    case "=":
      scale = Math.min(2, scale + 0.1);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
});

function rotate(x, y, rotation) {
  const panXX = x * Math.cos((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panXY = y * Math.sin((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panYY = y * Math.cos((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panYX = x * Math.sin((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panX = panXX + panXY;
  const panY = panYY - panYX;
  return { x: panX, y: panY };
}

(function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  const imgX = imgWidth * x;
  const imgY = imgHeight * y;

  const ox = canvas.width / 2 - imgX;
  const oy = canvas.height / 2 - imgY;

  const { x: rx, y: ry } = rotate(imgX, imgY, rotation);

  const matrix = new DOMMatrix()
    .translate(ox, oy)
    .rotate(rotation)
    .translate(-ox, -oy)
    .translate(rx, ry)
    .translate(ox, oy)
    .scale(scale)
    .translate(-ox, -oy);

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.setTransform(matrix);

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);

  ctx.resetTransform();

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  ctx.fillRect(canvas.width / 2 - 5, canvas.height / 2 - 5, 10, 10);
})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
pre {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<pre>
  Hotkeys
  ---
  Rotate: r
  Zoom out: -
  Zoom in: =
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [divide mouse movement](https://jsfiddle.net/gp84fecr/) by the current scale

```
x = lastX + dX / imgWidth / scale;
y = lastY + dY / imgHeight / scale;
```